# Mongodb Update into three level embedded document only on field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update three level Embedded document only one field. i am posting my data below in which I am trying to update only one field into the  document. here is my  Collection in which i am trying to update **View** value.  `{
  "_id": "5bbc7614b6160b29f05854c7",
  "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:34:12.604Z"
  "subcategories": [
    {
      "status": "1",
      "_id": "5bbc762fb6160b29f05854c8",
      "createdAt": "2018-10-09T09:34:39.008Z",
      "videos": [
        {
          "views": 0,
          "createdAt": "2018-10-12T11:40:08.752Z",
          "_id": "5bc08818ed05cf1c5e01103c",
          "user_id": "5ba08df7a68f5f1e43f05983",
          "description": "sdf",
          "size": "30.76 MB",
          "duration": "11:11",
          "video": "https://www.gpnext.org"
        },
        {
          "views": 10,
          "createdAt": "2018-10-12T11:40:08.752Z",
          "_id": "5bc08818ed05cf1c5e01103d",
          "user_id": "5ba08df7a68f5f1e43f05984",
          "description": "qwerty",
          "size": "35.76 MB",
          "duration": "10:10",
          "video": "https://www.gpnext1.org"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}`

I am trying to update **Views** value only but when i am executing bellow mentioned query it is deleting all video data and inserting only views field there. can someone guide me to update Views value without effecting other fields values. here is my query for updating view value.

`VideoCategory.findOneAndUpdate(
      {'subcategories.videos._id' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.video_id)}, 
      {   $set : 
               {
                   'subcategories.$.videos': {
                        'views' : 4
                   } 
               }
      },
      function(err, category){ 
         if (err)
            return res.send({ status: false, message: 'error in Increment'});
         else
            return res.json({ status: true, message: 'View incremented'});
      }
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positional operator (`$`) works only for arrays with one-level depth. In your case you need [positional filtered](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) operator which is available in MongoDB 3.6 or higher. Try:

```
db.col.update(
    { _id: "5bbc7614b6160b29f05854c7" }, 
    { $set: { "subcategories.$[subcategory].videos.$[video].views": 4 }}, 
    { arrayFilters: [ { "subcategory._id": "5bbc762fb6160b29f05854c8" }, { "video._id": "5bc08818ed05cf1c5e01103c" } ] })
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not modifying my document data. and by mongodb version is 3.6.6.

Comment: @Priyanklohan as far as I remember this was tested on 4.0, are you able to upgrade ?

Answer (score 0):

You set json object with only view key, thats why all other data expect "view" are deleted, in this case you need to use positional operator twice, like this

`{
   $set : {
     "subcategories.$.videos.$.views": "4"
 }`

But MongoDb has limitation on positional operator.
**The positional operator can be used only once in a query.**
Here is the issue link https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

I suggest two solution, but highly recommend to use first one

- Create another Video Collection, and save video _id(pointer) into your array, than you can easily make any update query you want
- Fetch your data, then do some changes, after that update whole data you fetched